# WCF: Why WCF for a Windows Forms application?

Tags: wcf, windows

I want to develop a simple Windows Forms application in C# using WPF and MVVM that will connect to an SQL server installed on a different machine. So I've read that, even for a simple structure like that, some developers would use WCF and make their application Service Oriented. I totally understand that SOA is the way to go with WebApps and SilverLight, but I don't see why, for a simple situation like a Winform and an SQL Server, would somebody use WCF. I would really appreciate if somebody could give me a couple of good reasons why to use WCF in my WinForm application (considering that the SQL Server will be in the same network with the clients)?

Thanks,
Aris

Comment: There is no reason.  Just connect to the server via a connex string and be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need it, don't use it :)

But you should consider whether there are plans to change the application - for example, to convert it to a web app or Silverlight. In that case, having a service which does the database access will make the conversion easier. Personally, I think this is usually over engineering, but it may make sense for your application if you foresee one such change in the near future.

Comment: I agree and that's what I did. This project will not be converted to a Web App so there is no reason to add services.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use WCF?  Nope.

In my opinion, though, there aren't too many reasons NOT to create a WCF service for this sort of work.

Using WCF services for your different layers instead of class libraries is an excellent way to go.  Using WCF, you can control how your components are hosted (IIS and http all the way down to in-process with named pipes) and where they're located.

WCF doesn't add much overhead and in return you get a bunch of benefits.

The point isn't necessarily to worry about SOA, but more to think ahead about flexibility and better reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a particularly compelling reason, other than habit.  When you do something the same way for 99% of your projects, it's often just as easy to do it the same way for the other 1% if it doesn't go actively against your requirements.

The only other reason I can think of would be if you're writing something that could, potentially, be really useful externally or as a web-app.  Using WCF in that instance would allow any client which could connect to the host (web browser, external application, or whatever) to connect to your library without you having to modify things after the fact.

If you know for (relatively) certain that this will only be a windows application run on the desktop of your own organizations' employees, I don't see a reason to use WCF in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line is that you're on a network so WCF or any web service makes sense.

Your network calls are all going to be async (or should be!). That's easy to do with WCF. Not so much with direct connections.

Even WinForm applications are connected these days.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't believe in creating services for everything, just to be creating services. Create a service when you *know* that you have a consumer for that service. Don't just say, "well, we might use it from another application some day", and call that an excuse for a service.

Services should be planned. The service contracts should be those which are required by their consumers. No consumers, no contracts, so no service.